# Java regular expression "( *|)": what does the pipe do?

Tags: java, regex

I'm studying a Java code that uses the regular expression `"( *|)"`. What does the pipe do in this expression?

So far I understood it works the same way as the expression for a group of optional spaces, i.e. `"( *)`.

Comment: zero or more spaces OR nothing = zero or more spaces

Comment: If you paste that in https://regex101.com/ you get a description of what each bit does on the right

Comment: Well I think the RHS of that alternation is empty, i.e. we could just use `\s*` and have the same effect.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ` *` and `\s*` is not the "same effect".

Comment: @laune Yes I know, but the only way to write zero or more _spaces_ would be `[ ]*` and it still be readable, and I didn't want to throw off the OP.

Comment: Why do you need the brackets for space, a single character? No functional purpose, only for readability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe ('|') simply means 'or'. At the one side we have regex for zero or more spaces, on the other side we have nothing - so it will match zero or more spaces or an empty string.

Comment: Yes, but what does `|`do? Answer the question, please!

Comment: You're right, I added more explanation.

Comment: That confirms my assumption that the pipe is useless in this regular expression, right?

Comment: Yes, in this case it is, because zero spaces is nothing as well.

Answer (score 1):

It Indicates that a match can be one of the two terms on either side of the pipe.

[look here](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/junos-cli-regular-expressions-with-pipe-usage-overview.html)